# How do I fix yield not working in while loop?

Tags: while-loop, unity-game-engine, 2d

I get no console errors, but all of them isntantiate at the same time, so they are all one unit, and I want a delay between their spawn. (they are enemies traveling a path)

```
#pragma strict

// Instantiate a rigidbody then set the velocity
var projectile : Transform;
var cnt : int = 0;

function Update () {
    if (buttonFeatures.started) {
            while (cnt < 4) {
        // Instantiate the projectile at the position and rotation of this transform
                    wait();
                    var clone : Transform;
                    clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
                    cnt++;
    } 
  }
}

function wait(){
    yield WaitForSeconds (10);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you're trying to something similar to `yield` from `Update()`, which can't be done.

You can't obviously block `Update()` for 10 seconds, but calling a method that uses`yield` will return *immediately *and start a [coroutine](http://docs.unity3d.com/412/Documentation/ScriptReference/index.Coroutines_26_Yield.html) with that method, so what you're seeing is:

- Update calls `wait()`
- Update keeps going without waiting for `wait()` to return
- `wait()` starts waiting for 10 seconds on it's own as a coroutine
- Update continues through the loop, calling `wait()` 3 more times, not waiting each time.

To confirm this you can change `wait()`:

```
function wait(){
    yield WaitForSeconds (10);
    Debug.Log("Done Waiting"); //You'll see 3 of these pop up in your console in 10 seconds later
}
```

You have two main options here. Either replace `wait()` with your logic:

```
function Update () {
    if (buttonFeatures.started) {
        while (cnt < 4) {
            InstantiateProjectile(cnt*10)// Instantiate the projectile at the position and rotation of this transform in X seconds. This will return immediately
            cnt++;
        }
    } 
}

function InstantiateProjectile(delay : int){
    yield WaitForSeconds(delay);
    var clone : Transform;
    clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation);
}
```

Or start a co-routine in `Start()`:

```
function Start(){
  UpdateProjectiles();
}

function UpdateProjectiles (){
    while(true){
        if (buttonFeatures.started) {
                while (cnt < 4) {

                    yield WaitForSeconds (10); //This works because it's not in Update
                    var clone : Transform;
                    clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation); // Instantiate the projectile at the position and rotation of this transform
                    cnt++;
                } 
         } 
     yield; //This causes this coroutine to behave the way Update would (running once a frame)
    }
}
```

The `while(true)` in the second example might be a little alarming, but it's performance is no different than using `Update()` because of the `yield`. In fact, many people use the majority of their "traditional" `Update()` logic in co-routines, as they allow better encapsulation of state management logic, and are great for periodic tasks.

Note: I didn't want to distort your code too much and obscure it's meaning, but you might want to reconsider certain parts of your code:

- You have a `while` loop with a count, that can easily be a `for` loop.
- You have a loop that seems to be replacing objects. `Instantiate` can be one of the most expensive calls you can make, because for every call you make to it, eventually you'll pay the cost of the GC cleaning up an object.

  You don't want to be destroying lots of objects and calling `Instantiate` to replace them with identical ones, because the GC will start slowing your game to a standstill keeping up. Right now as your code stands, if projectiles start being spawned in a situation where they're being destroyed very quickly, I won't be surprised if the game completely freezes.

  Instead, prefer *reusing* objects, with object pools. There are tutorials on how to do it, such as [this one](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling). At the most basic level, it can be something as simple as giving your projectiles a `Reset` method. Then you could replace `Destroy` with a method that calls `Reset` and stores them in a `Stack` or `List`, where they can be accessed again. But you'll want to encapsulate all that logic, so look at that tutorial for specifics.

Comment: It works, except now it clones one right ontop of the other, so when the projectile gets there it -2 on the enemy health (because there's 2 in the same place) the others after the second one follow as they should though.

Comment: I was hoping you'd take the time to understand what's going on in both examples and adapt them to your use. They're just meant to be examples of what both approaches do (I actually didn't expect them to compile). And you're not making it clear which approach you used. I'd say open a new question with the code you ended up with.

Comment: It worked and I have messed with it in many ways, but found no solution, that is why I responded. I have since just disabled the renderer on the script and renabled it elsewhere. Thanks. Thread over.

Comment: I'm happy if that works for you, but I'd still be glad to help get your original approach working, since disabling the renderer isn't fixing the problem as much as it's hiding it (the performance penalty will still be there). The problem is fixing that isn't actually related to your original question, it doesn't require anything further with yield, but rather changing the logic you're using. If you want to open a new question with the code that was making clones (maybe on UnityAnswers/the game-dev SE site, since it's getting less general), I'll do my best to see what the underlying problem is.

Comment: I like it as it is (instantiating and destroying itself), because this is just for the experience with no huge idea/concept behind the project. Thanks for your assistance, and I would put it in unity answers, but their response times are absolutely atrocious and and require the approval of a mod (with good reason), so it might go unposted/unnoticed for several days, and I only post when my patience is weared thin, so that I can get assistance, because I have done googling and not found an answer, or not found an answer I find <i> good enough </i>. So S.O. is my preferred option.

Answer (score -1):

replace this line instead of making the function call:

yield return new WaitForSeconds(10);

Comment: This is the syntax for C#, not related to the problem.